# How to read line in C

Tags: c, file, file-io, ansi-c

I want to reach line in file(*.txt)

My file includes three type. Firstly number of lines-1, secondly word and number, thirdly a query in last line.

For example;

5

dog 3

school 2

apple 2

car 1

cat 4

spoon food heart game stone pen

```
FILE *fp;
char arr[10][5];
char times[10];
int numberOfLines;
char queryTemp[1000];
fp = fopen("deneme.txt","r");
fscanf(fp,"%d",&numberOfLines);
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    fscanf(fp,"%s %d",arr[i],times[i]);     
}
fscanf(fp,"%s",querySubmissionsTemp);
```

Where am I wrong? How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You are inputting `numberOfLines`, but you are then inputting 10 lines regardless of the entry.

```
fscanf(fp,"%d",&numberOfLines);
for(int i=0;i<numberOfLines;i++)
```

Also, I don't see a declaration for `querySubmissionsTemp`.

```
fscanf(fp,"%s",queryTemp);
```

Incorporating BLUEPIXY's comment:

```
char arr[10][5];
```

`char[5]` is small. You need to include space for the `\0` null terminator at the end of a string.

`char times[10];` shoud be `int times[10];`

`fscanf(fp,"%s %d",arr[i],times[i]);` should be `fscanf(fp,"%4s %d",arr[i], &times[i]);` (4 is small size, already pointed out)

```
fscanf(fp,"%s",queryTemp);
```

This reads one word. Check out `fgets`.

Comment: That part of your code looks OK. Does it compile? Does it run? Does it give an error?

Comment: other problem 1) `char arr[10][5];` `char[5]` is small. 2) `char times[10];` shoud be `int times[10];` 3) `fscanf(fp,"%s %d",arr[i],times[i]);` should be `fscanf(fp,"%4s %d",arr[i], &times[i]);` (4 is small size, already pointed out) 4.1) `fscanf(fp,"%s",queryTemp);` this reads one word.

Comment: Thanks to your answers. Please forget it. :)

Comment: Now, I define four variable.

The first variable is justNumber.Its type is int and It includes the number of the first line.

The second variable is table[4][10]. Its type is char and It includes the words on the lines. For example table[0] will assign to "car". Similar to, table[1] will assign to "school".

The third variable is numbers[4]. Its type is int and It includes the numbers on the end of lines. For example numbers[0] will assign to 3 and numbers[1] will assign to 2.

Comment: The last variable is query. Its type is char and It includes the words on the last line. For example, query[0] will assign to "spone" and query[1] will assign to "stone".

How can I this?

Comment: You aren't being at all clear. Please edit your question to ask what you really want to know. If you don't want us to focus on your bad code, correct it. If you are going to tell us that your program crashed, run it through a debugger to tell us where and how it crashed. Read the "How to ask a good question" document for other good tips: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

//The length of the maximum of one word
#define WORD_SIZE 10

//S(10) => "10"
#define S_(n) #n
#define S(n) S_(n)

typedef struct pair {
    char word[WORD_SIZE+1];
    int number;
} Data; //Relevant data put together

int wordCount(const char *s);

int main(void){
    FILE *fp;
    int i, numberOfLines, numberOfQWords;
    Data *arr;
    char temp[1024], **query, *qword;

    fp = fopen("deneme.txt","r");
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &numberOfLines);
    arr = malloc(numberOfLines * sizeof(*arr));

    for(i=0; i<numberOfLines; i++){
        fscanf(fp,"%" S(WORD_SIZE) "s %d", arr[i].word, &arr[i].number);
    }
    fscanf(fp, " %1023[^\n]", temp);
    fclose(fp);

    numberOfQWords = wordCount(temp);
    query = malloc(numberOfQWords * sizeof(*query));
    for(i=0, qword = strtok(temp, " \t\n"); qword ; qword = strtok(NULL, " \t\n"), ++i){
        query[i] = qword;
    }

    {//check code
        for(int i=0; i<numberOfLines; i++){
            printf("%s, %d\n", arr[i].word, arr[i].number);
        }
        puts("\nquery:");
        for(int i=0; i<numberOfQWords; i++){
            printf("%s\n", query[i]);
        }
    }
    //deallocate
    free(arr);
    free(query);

    return 0;
}

int wordCount(const char *s){
    char prev = ' ';
    int wc = 0;

    while(*s){
        if(isspace(prev) && !isspace(*s)){
            ++wc;
        }
        prev = *s++;
    }
    return wc;
}
```